# kotlin constructor / spring mvc validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, kotlin

I have this kotlin data class:

```
data class Message(
    @field:NotEmpty
    val from: String?,
    @field:NotEmpty
    val to: List<String>?,
    @field:NotEmpty
    val subject: String?,
    val cc: List<String>?
)
```

and when I create a message using my spring mvc api:

```
@PostMapping("/messages")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@Valid message: Message) = service.create(message)
```

with the following data:

```
{
   "subject": "this is a test",
   "from": "test@test.com",
   "to": ["test@test.com"],
   "cc": []
}
```

I got 3 `org.springframework.validation.BindException`.
It seems that the validation occurs between the instantiation of the Message object and the setting of its properties.

Could anyone explain me what is happening and how validation/instantiation occurs in this case ?

Comment: Are you using `Hibernate validator` for validation and `Jackson for Kotlin` for JSON parsing?

Comment: Yes Hibernate validator and Jackson for Kotlin

Comment: In general Jackson parses and instantiates `message`, then Spring (before calling controller's method) passes it to Hibernate validator for validation. Could you provide more details about that exception?

Comment: [...] BindException [...] Field error in object 'message' on field 'from': rejected value [null]; [...] Field error in object 'message' on field 'to': rejected value [null]; [...] Field error in object 'message' on field 'subject': rejected value [null];

Comment: If what you say is true, then why I have this object after kotlin jackson mapping ? Message(from=null, to=null, subject=null, cc=null)

Comment: Looks like it is not a validation  problem, but binding one. Plese check whether your controller annotated with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177653/discussion-between-max-farsikov-and-louis-amoros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When u use `@Valid` then spring boot validate javax && hibernate validation. If you dont want to validate then remove `@Valid`. Also there missing `@RequestBody` .

With validation:

```
@PostMapping("/messages")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@Valid @RequestBody message: Message) = service.create(message)
```

without validation:

```
@PostMapping("/messages")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@RequestBody message: Message) = service.create(message)
```